# Exception handling in cxf rest client in Asyn call

Tags: web-services, jax-rs, cxfrs

I have a method "void deleteUser(User user)" exposed as cxf jaxrs web service. This void return type makes it as asynchronous web service. My deleteUser method sometime may throw the exception object and I need to catch that object in my cxf jax-rs client as well. But i am not getting any exception in my rest cxf client. 
Is there any way i can catch the exception for async rest call.

Answer (score 0):

You can access from response object.

```
Future<Response> response1 = null;
        try{
            response1 = client.async().get();
            Response response = response1.get();
            if(response.getStatus() == 200){
                // Success code here
                LOG.info("Returned with value: " + value);
            }else{
                LOG.info("Http request returned with status: "+ Status.fromStatusCode(response.getStatus()).getReasonPhrase()+ ", With error message "+ response.readEntity(String.class));
            }
        }catch(Exception ex){
            LOG.error("Errored", ex);
        }finally{
            if(client != null){
                client.close();
            }
        }
```